# MyBatis can't load configuration xml situated in project resource folder

Tags: java, configuration, mybatis

I am developing a java project with DB repositories and have faced with stupid question. I use MySQL and Mybatis 3.4.5. The configuration file (mybatis-config.xml) situated in resources/mybatis folder.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ8Vh.png)

I try to read it by the following code:

```
public class MySQLAttrRepo implements AttrRepo {
       public static final String CONFIGURATION_XML = "mybatis/mybatis-config.xml";
       private InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(CONFIGURATION_XML);
}
```

but get an exception

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mybatis/mybatis-config.xml
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The reason was wrong packaging in pom.xml. I set "pom" instead "jar".